# Testing a method of an object returned by a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a function that returns an object with many methods and I need to check one of the methods inside this returned object. I am using AngularJS and Karma+Jasmine as testing suite. How do I call methods inside the object returned by a function?

```js
function modalOptions() {
  .........
  return this.$q((resolve) => {
    // test accessable here
    this.solveModel = {
      save: () => {
        // test can't call save()
        this.saveToDB = this.toSendToDB;
      },
      cancel: () => { ...
      },
      delete: () => { ...
      }
    };
  });
}
```

My test is somewhat like this...

```js
it('should save modal with the data', function() {

  scope.$apply();
  expect(vm.modalOptions).toBeDefined();

  vm.toSendToDB = true; // hard-coded
  vm.savedToDB = undefined // default value from other controller

  spyOn(vm, 'modalOptions').and.callThrough();
  console.log(vm.modalOptions()); // gives weird response: c{$$state: Object{status: 0}} instead of the solveModal object

  expect(vm.toSendToDB).toBeTruthy();
  expect(vm.savedToDB).toBeTruthy();

});
```

Comment: don't you just have to do something like `vm.modalOptions().then(function(value){console.log(value);})` to get the solveModal object? because it returns a promise no?

Comment: actually this was what I was doing but the test was not entering inside the then call. Later, I just kept manually calling the functions in order and it worked. Weird but worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can not comment yet, but the promise has to be resolved and the solveModel passed to it, in order for solveModel to be returned. Where do you resolve the promise?

Comment: Not sure how it got resolved but I was able to access `solveModal.save()` directly after calling `vm.modalOptions()` before it. The function didn't have reject so I suppose it's always resolved with the solveModal object (solveModal is initially { } ). Is this even possible?

Comment: The [$q docu](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) states, that $q gets a function as argument which itself has two arguments: resolve and reject. In your case reject has been omitted for whatever reason but you could add it. Inside the function passed to $q you have to call resolve yourself in order to resolve the promise. If of course you immediately resolve within `vm.modalOptions()` then the behavior you described could happen. However, you can not rely on it because its asynchronous. Maybe you can provide the exact code of the function?